# Postgresql function per row

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, parameters

I am currently learning `postgresql` and have a noob question. If I have a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rectangle
(
    width int,
    length int
);
```

And a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Area()
RETURNS int AS $area$
declare
    area int;
BEGIN
   SELECT (width*length)  into area FROM rectangle;
   return area ;
END;
$area$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I call it like this:

```
select width, length, area() from rectangle;
```

I get results like this:

```
width  |  length  |  area
-------------------------
2      |     3    |    6
4      |     3    |    6
5      |     2    |    6
```

Which shows that the area function is working but it is only using the first entry in the table and not the corresponding row. What am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have assumed the function will "know" it is in a row, and therefore use that row. `Not true.` The function is independent of the row, and you must "pass" values from the row into that function. While this is probably just a simple example, you don't need to use a function for this and you should just use (width*length) directly in the query

Comment: I see what I did wrong. So in general it is best to send in a `pk` for the function and add a `WHERE`

Comment: why did you use `select width,length,(length*width) as area from rectangle` >> ?? this is not a good situation to implement a `Function`

Comment: "so in general ..." mmm, `not really,` the sample functions below both "abstract" the area calculation from any physical implementation of length or width, so the function could be used in any relevant situation. If you base a function on a PK then the function can only be used in one situation. Also note that in the sample functions below they do not need to use `select`, because you pass the length and the width which have already been selected. Passing a pk would require another select, which is not great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Area(integer, integer)
RETURNS int AS $area$
declare
    area int;
BEGIN
   SELECT ($1 * $2)  into area ;
   return area ;
END;
$area$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then on your query:

```
select width, length, area(width, length) from rectangle;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function you are getting the values from one undetermined row from the table. It is necessary to pass the parameters to the function

```
create or replace function area (
    width int, length int
) returns int as $area$

   select width * length;

$area$ language sql;
```

It can be plain SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more efficient:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Area(integer, integer)
RETURNS int AS 
$body$
BEGIN
   return ($1 * $2) ;
END;
$body$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql 
IMMUTABLE;
```

Reasons:

- No SQL evaluating;
- An IMMUTABLE function cannot modify the database and is guaranteed to return the same results given the same arguments forever. This category allows the optimizer to pre-evaluate the function when a query calls it with constant arguments. For example, a query like SELECT ... WHERE x = 2 + 2 can be simplified on sight to SELECT ... WHERE x = 4, because the function underlying the integer addition operator is marked IMMUTABLE. (see [more](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-volatility.html)).